# Occupied or preoccupied?

Tags: word-choice

Lenny is strolling around the park, bored, when he notices a squirrel jumping around in a tree. He sits down on a bench to watch it.

Then something else happens somewhere else.

Back in the park, Lenny is still occupied/preoccupied, watching the squirrel with great interest.

Question: Should I use "occupied" or "preoccupied" or do either sound odd here? (I am aware of the difference between the words but I'm still not sure what would be more natural to use)

Comment: If Lenny is sitting on a bench watching squirrels, he isn't occupied at all. But he might be [preoccupied](https://www.lexico.com/definition/preoccupied) with his thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

In OP's context, ***preoccupied*** is the better choice.

The ***pre-*** prefix implies ***already***, which by further implication suggests there's *something else* that Lenny *should* be doing. Being "occupied" usually implies doing something meaningful / productive, whereas being "preoccupied" often means doing or paying attention to something relatively pointless (daydreaming, watching squirrels, etc.).

From [WikiDiff...](https://wikidiff.com/occupied/preoccupied)

> *As adjectives the difference between **occupied** and **preoccupied** is that **occupied** is "reserved, engaged" while **preoccupied** is "concerned with something else; distracted; giving one's attention elsewhere".*

---

Here's [an interesting chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=occupied%20with%20his%20thoughts%2Cpreoccupied%20with%20his%20thoughts&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Coccupied%20with%20his%20thoughts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpreoccupied%20with%20his%20thoughts%3B%2Cc0) showing how usage has changed over time in this area...

[image]

...where it seems unlikely that the real-world nature of introspection / contemplation / daydreaming would have changed all that much over the past century. So I think you can take it for granted the difference between these two words isn't as clear-cut as some people might ***like*** it to be.

Comment: So "preoccupied" is ok even though he really hasn't anything else he should be doing?

Comment: Yes. I made the point (about the "meaning" of the ***pre-*** prefix) because I figured that would make sense for ***most*** contexts where we might have to choose between the "base" word *(**occupied**)* and the "marked" form *(**preoccupied**)*. You might perhaps think of ***pre-*** as implying "otherwise" or "differently" in the sense of "not actively engaged in doing anything meaningful" - but nevertheless "busy" (doing nothing in particular, but with one's attention definitely diverted by *something*).

Comment: This answer is very overblown and "preoccupied" here in the OP's question would be odd indeed.

Comment: @Lambie: I think you're preoccupied with point-scoring! There ***is*** a significant difference in how the two forms are used today, and OP's context ("[pre-]occupied" watching a squirrel) is ***precisely*** the kind of activity that we're more likely to associate with the "derived" version today. You may see things differently, but to my mind Lenny would normally only be "occupied" in this context if "watching the squirrel" was a task that he'd been assigned to carry out for some reason.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica You must be kidding. I don't give a you-know-what about points but I do believe in tailoring answers to obvious levels of knowledge shown by OPs. The change of usage **over time** is really irrelevant at this level.

Comment: I think the usage change (which I wasn't consciously aware of before checking NGrams) is highly relevant for many learners, because knowing that will help them understand ***why*** they find lots of (older?) written instances that apparently contradict the distinction I'm making here. Just as the second sentence in my answer goes some what to explaining ***why*** native speakers tend to make this distinction. An "explanation" that appears to "make sense" is more useful (and easier to *remember*) that an "answer" than just says "this means this, and that means that".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica The meanings have not changed at all, and occupied with his thoughts and preoccupied with them is exactly what I defined. In any event, I really did not appreciate that remark about points. If I were after points, I wouldn't not answer for days at a time....

Answer (score -1):

An answer for an English-language learner.

This is very simple:

to be occupied = to be busy

to be preoccupied = to be worried about something else.

- **Lenny is occupied** watching the squirrel. = busy
- Lenny **is preoccupied about** the squirrel because it looks too skinny. = worried
- Lenny is preoccupied by other matters but he is watching the squirrel.

Comment: It's true that in *some* contexts, "preoccupation" might imply "worry". But it's just as natural to say someone's preoccupied with thinking about ***good*** things. Normally, all that matters is that the preoccupied person ***isn't** focused on productive / relevant things*. I see no reason whatsoever to suppose Lenny is actually concerned for the squirrel's well-being in the cited context. It's just holding his (probably, not particularly focused) attention.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica The definition you cite is actually saying more what I am saying: As adjectives the difference between occupied and preoccupied is that occupied is "reserved, engaged" while preoccupied is "concerned with something else; distracted; giving one's attention elsewhere".