# "Occupy one's mind" vs "Preoccupy someone" vs "Prey on one's mind"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, difference, idioms, idioms-in-context

Imagine something gets so important to you that takes up your mind and occupies your thoughts in the manner that you constantly think about it.

**A)** Ana, what James told me at the party last night has .................. 
**B)** What did he tell you Sam? 
**A)** Perhaps he's had a fertility test recently which shows he's unable to have kids. 
**B)** How come? 
**A)** Yea, he's unfortunately infertile! 
**B)** Oh, sad...

**1. [preoccupied me](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/preoccupy)** 
[To be the main thought in someone's mind, causing other things to be forgotten]
**2. [occupied my mind](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/occupy)** 
[If something occupies your mind, thoughts, or attention, or if it occupies you, you think about it a lot] 
**3. [preyed on my mind](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/prey-on-somebody-s-mind)** 
[If a problem preys on your mind, you cannot stop thinking about it]

As you can see through the provided links above, all three provided options are so close in meaning that it is somehow unlikely for a nonnative one to be able to distinguish between them.

Therefore, I was wondering if you could give me a hand and let me know if there is any significant nuance between these choices regarding my needed message.

To me they all mean the same thing, but that's what I need you to confirm.

Comment: Hard to see any difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Occupied or preoccupied?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/241845/occupied-or-preoccupied)

Comment: You can be [*preoccupied with anticipation*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22preoccupied+with+anticipation%22) *of **good** things* you expect to happen in the future. But anything that ***preys on your mind*** is ALWAYS bad, whether it's happened yet or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the verb *preoccupy* is not very natural - I would be much more likely to use the adjectival phrase *preoccupied with* (also without a qualifier *He was preoccupied.)*

*Occupied my mind*, while it makes sense, is likewise not a very natural phrase to me.

*Prey on* is different, because it implies that it is worrying the person - *occupy* and *preoccupy* do not have that implication (though of course they do not exclude it). I can be preoccupied with something I am looking forward to, and I would not say that was "preying on" my mind.

Comment: Well, then may I ask you what is the most natural idiom / expression to be used in this sense @colin Fine? I need the implication of making one’s mind busy in the manner that you continuously think about it.

Comment: Various phrases, but not _occupy_ or _preoccupy_. _It's going round in my head_, or _I can't get it out of my head_, or _It keeps coming back to me_. It could be _mind_ where I've said _head_, but for me, _head_ is more natural.